# If $\sum x_{n}$ and $\sum y_{n}$ are convergent show that $\sum (x_{n}+y_{n})$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof

because $\sum  x_{n}$ and  $\sum y_{n}$ are convergent

then

$\sum  x_{n}=|x_{1}+x_{2}.....|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$ and

$\sum y_{n}=|y_{1}+y_{2}.....|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$

then $\sum x_{n}+y_{n}$

$|x_{1}+x_{2}.....|+|y_{1}+y_{2}.....|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2}=\epsilon $

Comment: Not following your sums at all.  What's $n$?  It looks like a dummy index variable, but if so then it can't appear on the right.  And I have no guess what your $\cdots$ might mean.

Comment: I see the edit and it helps a little, but not enough.  I think you mean to write $X=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i$ and then choose an index $N$ large enough so that $|X-\sum_{i=0}^{N} x_i|<\frac {\epsilon}2$.  Then similarly for $Y$ and then ....

Comment: @AndresMejia The problem does not tell it absolutely convengent or not

Comment: In your "proof" it looks as if both series converge to $0$, which doesn't have to be the case. And also, a number and its absolute value do **NOT** have to be the same thing (e.g. $-5\neq|-5|$), so why "$\sum x_n=|\sum x_n|$" (and same for the other one)?

Comment: oops I got many down vote

Comment: @Fourier, I don't know why. You asked a question and gave an attempt. Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Fourier I agree. Perhaps it is because this question is a "duplicate" in some sense, but I upvoted anyhow :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is maybe an atypical solution that I think is kind of neat and in some small way "the reason" why this is true.

View $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x,y)=x+y$ as a continuous function. Let $a$ be the first limit and $b$ the second, with $a_n$ the partial sums of the first and $b_n$ the partial sums of the second. Then $\lim (a_n,b_n)$ converges $\iff$ $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ converge and $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$.

Hence,
$$a+b=f(a,b)=f(\lim (a_n,b_n))=\lim f(a_n,b_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_n\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_n+b_n).$$

**remark:** this would have worked for any continuous function. Say $f: \mathbb R  \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto xy$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$ converges when the two said sums do. This has very little to do with sums  (as evidenced by my bare-boned notation) and a lot to do with continuous functions and sequences.

*Here is something more along your lines* that you should work out:

the sequence of partial sums are both cauchy, so it will suffice to see that the desired sequence is cauchy: let  $n>k$.

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_n+b_n)-\sum_{i=1}^{k}(a_n+b_n)\right|=\left|\sum_{k}^{n}(a_n+b_n) \right| \leq \left| \sum_{k}^{n} a_n+\sum_{k}^{n} b_n \right| \leq \left|\sum_{k}^{n}a_n \right|+\left|\sum_{k}^{n} b_n \right|.$$

Notice what happens to the right hand side as $k$ becomes sufficiently large.

Comment: I really like this answer. This is a good example of a question which intuitively is obvious, but requires some thinking to formally prove.